# Flutter lib size and assets size too big

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter2.0

I am unable to encounter why my lib size is so big.
Even the assets folder is showing 35MB but the image stored in the assets folder is 500KB only, I am unable to locate the issue that caused the app size to get this big.

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
app-release.aab (total compressed)                                        122 MB
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
  BUNDLE-METADATA/
    com.android.tools.build.libraries                                       7 KB
    com.android.tools.build.obfuscation                                   545 KB
  base/
    root                                                                   48 KB
    lib                                                                    81 MB
    Dart AOT symbols accounted decompressed size                            7 MB
      package:flutter                                                       3 MB
      package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar                                 762 KB
      dart:convert                                                        569 KB
      dart:core                                                           395 KB
      package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker                               296 KB
      dart:typed_data                                                     254 KB
      dart:ui                                                             225 KB
      dart:collection                                                     148 KB
      dart:io                                                             142 KB
      dart:async                                                          121 KB
      package:stupad                                                      112 KB
      package:syncfusion_flutter_core                                      78 KB
      package:intl                                                         67 KB
      package:win32                                                        52 KB
      package:vector_math                                                  52 KB
      package:flutter_staggered_grid_view                                  45 KB
      dart:isolate                                                         38 KB
      package:characters                                                   32 KB
      package:flutter_local_notifications                                  30 KB
      package:google_mobile_ads                                            28 KB
    res                                                                   500 KB
    assets                                                                 35 MB
    dex                                                                     4 MB
    manifest                                                                5 KB
    resources.pb                                                           84 KB
  META-INF/
    KEY.SF                                                                 12 KB
    KEY.RSA                                                                 1 KB
    MANIFEST.MF                                                            11 KB
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_mobile_ads:
  google_ml_kit: ^0.3.0
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^19.1.59
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+4
  flutter_native_timezone: ^1.0.10
```

Comment: would you please post your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: I have added pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

run: flutter clean
after: build again
now you see a Miracle